# Problem when prints accents in Java with Input Stream and Argox

Tags: java, printing, encode

I trying to print some data in Argox OS-214 Plus (USB) with Java. It's printing the text properly, less the accented letters (including ç).

I think it can be an encode problem when sending the data to the Printer.

I tried lots of encoding things, but nothing helped me out.

```java
PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

DocPrintJob job = printService.createPrintJob();

// normal text being printed, with the accents normals.
System.out.println(text);

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
/*
// other tentative without success
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(new String(text.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UFT-8"));
*/

DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;

Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);

job.print(doc, null);

is.close();
```

Comment: Try flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8

Comment: I already tried and got an error `sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor` :( But thanks!